# console.log not working on any karma project

Tags: javascript, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

UPDATE: tl;dr; I updated my npm packages and couldn't see any `console.log` output anymore in karma.  Looks like it's b/c of a behavior change that only shows `console.log` output at the `LOG_DEBUG` level and hides it at `LOG_INFO`.  When was that change made and is there a way to revert it?

ORIGINAL: When I run karma from a windows command prompt I cannot see the output of `console.log`.  I used to see it fine in many projects, but now it's suddenly not working in any of my projects.  This seems to have changed after I ran `npm update` in one project.  I did not `npm update` any other project, but they all stopped working.

I created an MCVE with a clean project and I still see the same behavior.  Here's a list of the installed packages in my clean project (output from `npm list`)

```
C:\...\mvce>npm list
mvce@1.0.0 C:\...\mvce
+-- jasmine-core@2.5.2
+-- karma@1.5.0
+-- karma-chrome-launcher@2.0.0
+-- karma-jasmine@1.1.0
+-- karma-phantomjs-launcher@1.0.2
`-- phantomjs@2.1.7
```

and here's the config code

```
karma.conf.js

module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        autoWatch: false,
        singleRun: true,
        basePath: ".",
        frameworks: ["jasmine"],
        logLevel: "INFO",
        browsers: ["PhantomJS", "Chrome"],
        files: ["test.js"]
    });
};



test.js

describe("describe", function(){
    it("it", function(){
        console.log("test");
    });
});
```

Note I have already tried adding both of these to my `karma.conf.js`.  They make no difference.

```
        client: {
            captureConsole: true
        }

        // or

        loggers: [
            { type: "console" }
        ]
```

NOTE: I've seen [this issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-mocha/issues/47) on karma github, none of the suggestions there help.  Also, it's describing a setup w/ mocha, I'm using jasmine - and the official workaround is to use `captureConsole` which I tried.

I also created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/ykosbie/f152faf2c2d9fc6d33c06f43942209a2) for this issue.

Environment info:

- Windows 10 Home w/ all current updates
- Node v7.2.1
- Chrome 56

Comment: try to change to `it("it", function(done)` and then `done()` under the console.log

Comment: @ssuperczynski No change.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Looks like karma added a feature in v1.5.0 to filter console capture by log level.  Here's a link to the [git pull request](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/pull/2493) and the [code changes](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/commit/35965d9e996d462e471044b338ac038d2787c26d) showing what happened.  I couldn't find any updates in the docs about this new feature.  Based on the code changes, here are the new rules

You can configure `browserConsoleLogOptions` in your karma conf file to specify what messages should appear on your terminal output.  Set the `level` property to specify the maximum level that should be displayed.  To display all messages, set `level` to an empty string.

For my case, I needed to set it like this:

```
browserConsoleLogOptions: {
    terminal: true,
    level: ""
}
```

UPDATE: There's an [open git issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/2582) discussing this.  There are actually two changes in karma 1.5 that matter here.

1. They changed the order of severity for log messages so that `LOG` == `DEBUG`.    The severity used `LOG` > `INFO`. That means any project has log level set to `INFO` would show `console.log` messages in the old version and not show them in the new system.
2. As mentioned above they added support to filter console by log level with `browserConsoleLogOptions`.

Comment: Phew.  Thanks for this!  Future readers please note that this setting appears at the top level of config, as a peer to the `client` key, not within it, as implied by much of the discussion here (https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-mocha/issues/47)